# Class does not exist vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:790

Tags: laravel

I'm having problems finding where this error is coming from. 
Can anyone shed some light on this error?

I have cleared all cache files and checked the config files for errors.The file is physically there when I use the server's file explorer.

This error occurs on the staging server, running cpanel php7.1. Had no problems while using the local development server.

The stack trace:

```
[2019-07-06 06:44:49] online.ERROR: Class mollie does not exist {"userId":"70a84900-9fa7-11e9-a421-57dbf5e49d9b","exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class mollie does not exist at /home/serv/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:790)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/serv/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(790): ReflectionClass->__construct('mollie')
#1 /home/serv/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(667): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('mollie')
#2 /home/serv/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(615): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('mollie', Array)
#3 /home/serv/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(767): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('mollie', Array)
#4 /home/serv/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1225): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('mollie')
#5 /home/serv/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(175): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->offsetGet('mollie')
#6 /home/serv/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(144): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::resolveFacadeInstance('mollie')
#7 /home/serv/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(231): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::getFacadeRoot()
#8 /home/serv/app/app/Http/Controllers/PaymentController.php(62): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic('api', Array)
#9 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\PaymentController->preparePayment('starter')
```

the mollie class comes from the official Mollie payment package
https://github.com/mollie/laravel-mollie/blob/master/src/Facades/Mollie.php

I am using it the way the docs describe:

```
 $payment = Mollie::api()->payments()->create([
            'amount' => [
                'currency' => 'EUR',
                'value' => $totalAmount, // You must send the correct number of decimals, thus we enforce the use of strings
            ],
            'description' => $totalCoins,
            'webhookUrl' => route('order.hook'),
            'redirectUrl' => route('order.success'),
        ]);
```

This is the first occurance for Mollie in that method

Comment: can you share your class `mollie` and the code from your `PaymentController` which uses it?

Answer (score 0):

So in your `PaymentController` you are referencing a class called `mollie` which could not be found, physically it is there but you need to import it in your controller in order to be found.

So you might be missing some of this:

1. `use App\mollie;` // as an example of import / I don't know the namespace of the file
2. in your `class mollie` you forgot to add the `namespace`

Comment: I've updated my question, I am using 'use Mollie\Laravel\Facades\Mollie;'

Comment: after you've installed the package have you tried running `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: I am not able to run composer dump-autoload on the Cpanel server, unfortunately

Comment: but then how do you install your dependencies? Do you have a script that triggers `composer install` whenever you push changes? If you do, then add the `composer dump-autoload` at the bottom, also clear the cache.